# How to fade out and fade in the divs sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to fade out all elements sequentially, and then fade in all elements with new data.

Whats I've made only accomplish 50% of my goal as only the fadeIn happens sequentially, the fade out happens at the same time to all divs.

I would like to know what can I be doing wrong so that fadeout the elements happens sequentially.

Any thoughs how to solve this?

Css:

```
.class4 {
    width: 24%;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(174,174,174,0.50);
    background-image: url('http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/25126');
    background-position: 50% 6%;
    background-size: 90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
.class3 {
    width: 24%;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(174,174,174,0.50);
    background-image: url('http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/25126');
    background-position: 50% 6%;
    background-size: 90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
.class2 {
    width: 24%;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(174,174,174,0.50);
    background-image: url('http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/25126');
    background-position: 50% 6%;
    background-size: 90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
.class1 {
    width: 24%;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(174,174,174,0.50);
    background-image: url('http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/25126');
    background-position: 50% 6%;
    background-size: 90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
 var loadTime = 500;
            $('.class1, .class2, .class3, .class4').each(function (fadeInDiv) {
                //$(this).delay(fadeInDiv * 500).fadeIn(1000);
                $(this).fadeOut(loadTime, function () {
                    $(this).css('background-image', 'url("https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/15119")');
                    $(this).fadeIn(loadTime);
                    loadTime += 500;
                });
            });
        });
});
```

Html:

```
<input id = "btn" type="button" ><br><br>
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
<div class="class3"></div>
<div class="class4"></div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xudaR/61/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    var loadTime = 500;
    $('.class1, .class2, .class3, .class4').each(function(fadeInDiv) {

      $(this).fadeOut(loadTime, function() {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url("https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/15119")');

      }).data('delay', fadeInDiv * 300);

      $(this).fadeIn(loadTime);
      loadTime += 500;
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.class4 {
  width: 24%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(174, 174, 174, 0.50);
  background-image: url('http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/25126');
  background-position: 50% 6%;
  background-size: 90%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.class3 {
  width: 24%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(174, 174, 174, 0.50);
  background-image: url('http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/25126');
  background-position: 50% 6%;
  background-size: 90%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.class2 {
  width: 24%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(174, 174, 174, 0.50);
  background-image: url('http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/25126');
  background-position: 50% 6%;
  background-size: 90%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.class1 {
  width: 24%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(174, 174, 174, 0.50);
  background-image: url('http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/25126');
  background-position: 50% 6%;
  background-size: 90%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="btn" type="button">
<br>
<br>
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
<div class="class3"></div>
<div class="class4"></div>
```

Let me know if this is what you want: `code`:

http://jsfiddle.net/xudaR/66/

Comment: clicking button multiple times continuously don't work

Comment: This is just to start with. Also, you can reduce the delay.

Comment: That don't answer my query in any way

Comment: @Tushar This is normal. If you want click to override the current animation, check this jquery function : stop(true, true)

Comment: Hint: See `stop` method in jQuery

Comment: Hi thanks for the Answer, but if you notice, the first time all all divs are update first, and then the effect is  applied. i'm trying to update images only after fadeout. are you understanding what i'm trying? best regards

Comment: Hi @user1012181, Thanks! This is the solution! please update your answer so that i can mark it as correct :)

Comment: Hey @user1012181, please update you JSFiddle Link so that other people can find the correct fiddle too. Thanks!